# how to resolve this error Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

T[image: i Have a dataframe name content which have a column name New_Pair where these values reside want to pick unique and not_unique from new_Pair column for each row to a separate column name unique and not unique]

trying this:

```py
input_list = content.New_Pair
elements_count = collections.Counter(input_list)
content['unique'] = [element for element in input_list if elements_count[element] == 1]
content['not_unique'] = [element for element in input_list if elements_count[element] > 1]
```

when i am doing this:

Error: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: kindly reformat your question and follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: What's your `else` case? For instance, `[element if elements_count[element] == 1 else None for element in input_list]`

Comment: i am not getting this i tried this code on single value it worked?

Comment: Please check my answer @P_data